# Android: InputConnection - how to get composingtext correctly

Tags: android

I do backspace in textfield, and i need to set as composingText word or it part, that has left before cursor position. I must do that thing each time when i press backspace. So my step must be:

- get size of last word (or part of it);
- make it as composing text.

I try do it like this:

```
ic.setSelection(startWordPosition, word.length());
ic.setComposingText(word, 1);
```

All works good, while i don't test backspace in string like "a.a". It select all 3 characters, but when set, replace only part after dot.

Then i try make it like this:

```
ic.deleteSurroundingText(word.length(),0);
ic.setComposingText(word, 1);
```

But it not work correctly and delete sometimes text before my word(maybe because it currently compose).

---

Just find one more way that looks like right:

```
ic.finishComposingText();
ic.deleteSurroundingText(word.length(),0);
ic.setComposingText(word, 1);            
ic.setSelection(fullInputedString.length(),fullInputedString.length());
```

**Is it correct?**

**How should it be in right way?**

target sdk=8

Thanks!

---

**UPD:**
I found next solution for

```
ic.finishComposingText();
ic.deleteSurroundingText(wordForInsert.length(), 0);
ic.setComposingText(wordForInsert, 1);
```

And for latest android version i use appropriate method:

```
ic.setComposingRegion();
```

But this solution provide issue in standatrd android browser for 4.0v Android and latest.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the solution you have posted? what parameters did you send to setComposingRegion, wouldn't you still continue to have the same problem you mentioned in the question?